# Decimal to hex conversion c++ built-in function

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, built-in

Is there a built-in function in c++ that would take a decimal input from a user and convert it to hex and vice versa?? I have tried it using a function I've written but I was wondering if there is a built-in one to minimize the code a little bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Decimal to hex :-

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< std::hex << decimal_value; // int decimal_value
std::string res ( ss.str() );

std::cout << res;
```

Hex to decimal :-

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss  << hex_value ; // std::string hex_value
ss >> std::hex >> decimal_value ; //int decimal_value

std::cout << decimal_value ;
```

Ref: [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Comment: For the reading in, you can read straight into an integral type, and avoid the stringstreams and strings.

Comment: I agree with @juanchopanza . Basically for hex to decimal you can just do `int decimal_value = std::stoi(hex_value, nullptr, 16);`.

Comment: can also be done as a 1-liner: `auto res = (std::stringstream{} << std::hex << decimal_value).str();`

Answer (score 13):

Many compilers support the `itoa` function (which appears in the POSIX standard but not in the C or C++ standards).  Visual C++ calls it `_itoa`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char hexString[20];
itoa(value, hexString, 16);
```

Note that there is no such thing as a decimal value or hex value.  Numeric values are always stored in binary.  Only the string representation of the number has a particular radix (base).

Of course, using the `%x` format specifier with any of the `printf` functions is good when the value is supposed to be shown in a longer message.

Comment: > Numeric values are always stored in binary.  Can we read it with different way, eg. The value is 17,is (17)dec and (11)hex.the stored value doesn't change.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int DecToHex(int p_intValue)
{
    char *l_pCharRes = new (char);
    sprintf(l_pCharRes, "%X", p_intValue);
    int l_intResult = stoi(l_pCharRes);
    cout << l_intResult<< "\n";
    return l_intResult;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 35;
    DecToHex(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  And please don't encourage `using namespace std;`!

Comment: leaks memory! l_pCharRes is never freed.