# Convert Decimal value to Hexadecimal in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hex, type-conversion, decimal

How to convert a decimal value to Hexadecimal in visual studio C++.

For example, i want to convert decimal value 125 to Hexadecimal 7D.

I can do this in C# using `string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");`

How will i do the same operation in Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `std::stringstream` class to format the number like this:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << std::hex << 32768;
std::string hexValue = sstr.str();
```

Comment: It is giving error: stringstream not a member of std

Comment: `stringstream` is declared in `#include <sstream>`

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034349/2064516

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss  << hex_value ; // std::string hex_value
ss >> std::hex >> decimal_value ; //int decimal_value

std::cout << decimal_value ;
```

Comment: This is the opposite of the conversion requested.