# Optimizing conversion between bases - C++

Tags: c++, string, performance, optimization, converters

I am designing a cipher and need to convert between bases repeatedly in a loop.  I have optimized the everything else, but I'm not too familiar with C++ code, and and am trying to figure out how to make the conversion faster.

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
string digits = "0123456789abcdef";
string tohex(string number) {                        // Decimal to Hexadecimal function
    long length = number.length();
    string result = "";
    vector<long> nibbles;
    for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        nibbles.push_back(digits.find(number[i]));
    }
    long newlen = 0;
    do {
        long value = 0;
        newlen = 0;
        for ( long i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            value = (value * 10) + nibbles[i];
            if (value >= 16) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = value / 16;
                value %= 16;
            } else if (newlen > 0) {
                nibbles[newlen++] = 0;
            };
        };
        length = newlen;
        result = digits[value] + result;
    } while (newlen != 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: did you try running it through a profiler?

Comment: Try to ask the question of [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead if the code already works as expected but feels too slow :)

Comment: [there are ways in c++ to convert decimal to hex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20034297/238902) by the way.

Comment: `push_back` is gonna kill you.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, I think that's the least of the op's problems in the above code..

Comment: `result = digits[value] + result` is going to be `O(n²)` if done `O(n)` times. Don't do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In my case (cipher) the number will always fit within an int, so it works to do:

```
string tohex(string number) {
    int num = std::stoi(number);
    std::stringstream hexnumber;
    hexnumber << std::hex << num;
    return hexnumber.str();
}
```

This is better because it is simpler and uses the built-in std::hex method.

Comment: This only works providing the number fits within an int - otherwise you'll get an `out_of_range` exception thrown at you. If it's completely invalid it'll spew out `invalid_argument`

Comment: Some explanation of what this code does, what problem it solves and how it's better would be important here.