# Converting 2-Digit Decimal to Hexadecimal

Tags: c++, c, arduino, data-conversion

I'm a beginner-intermediate level Arduino coder trying to convert 2-digit decimal to hexadecimal for one of my projects. The code I made seems to work, but it seems much, much longer than it should be:

```
int decToHex(int ones, int tens) {
  int result = 0x00;
  if (tens == 0) {
    switch (ones) {
      case 0:
        result = 0x00;
        break;
      case 1:
        ...
      case 9:
        result = 0x09;
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch (tens) {
      case 1:
        switch (ones) {
          case 0:
            result = 0x0A;
            break;
          case 1:
            ...
          case 9:
            result = 0x13;
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        ...
      case 9:
        switch (ones) {
          ...
        }
        break;

    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any help shortening this code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you code is working and you want suggestions on how it can be improved then [codereview.se] is a more appropriate place for your question.

Comment: `return tens * 10 + ones;` should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to hex conversion c++ built-in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034297/decimal-to-hex-conversion-c-built-in-function)

Comment: What should be your result? If you `return 0x0A`, you wrote the return value in hex notation, but the return value will be decimal 10. An `int` is an `int`. You can't have a hex-int. If you want to show the value of an int in hex, the result must be a string. Or simply `printf("%x", result)`

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to input a 2 digit decimal value

and output it as a hex value.

```
unsigned int inputValue = 0;

if( 1 == scanf( "%u", &inputValue ) )
{
    if( 99 >= inputValue )
    {
        printf( %04x\n", inputValue );
    }

    else
    {
         // handle range error
    }
}

else
{
    // handle scanf() failure
}
```

for the posted function:

```
char * decToHex(unsigned int ones, unsigned int tens) 
{
    short int result = 0x0000;
    char *hexStr = NULL;

    if( NULL != (hexStr = malloc(7) ) )
    {
        // handle error and exit
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    unsigned short int totalValue = ones+ (10*tens);

    sprintf( hexStr, "0X%04x", totalValue );

    return hexStr;
}
```

Comment: Note: this answer does not handle negative input values

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. You want the hex representation of the Int printed as a string? See below. There is no difference except the representation in base 10 or base 16 really. Which can be printed differently.

```
int a = 10 * tens + ones;

printf("%x\n", a);
printf("0x%x\n", a);
```