# Converts Decimal To Hexadecimal In C++

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

Yesterday I wrote a program that converts Decimal to Hexadecimal.

But I did not satisfy my code because I think *my code needs something else*.
And I *want to know another solution* for this conversion.(eg-using quotient and remainder, using function or something else)

Can you help me?

//I really sorry for my English skill.

Here is my code,

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int power,num;
        
    cout << "Enter A Number: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Hexadecimal Number: ";

    //16^1to16^10 but you can find as you want eg-to 16^15...
    for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
    {
        power = pow(16,i);
        if(power > num)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++) //for hex num//if i=3, there will be two hex 
            {
                power = pow(16,(i-1)-k);    
                for(int j=15;j>=0;j--)
                {
                    power *= j;
                    if(power<=num)
                    {
                        cout << ch[j];
                        num = num-power;
                        break;
                    }
                    power = pow(16,(i-1)-k);
                }
            }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For another solution, do you mind using built-in tools of the C++ Standard library? If so, does this help? [Decimal to hex conversion c++ built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034297/decimal-to-hex-conversion-c-built-in-function)

Comment: If this is a school exercise, you are probably expected to realize that this is the same problem as separating a number's decimal digits, but using `% 16` and `/ 16` instead of `% 10` and `/ 10`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have from decimal to hex

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< std::hex << decimal_value; // int decimal_value
std::string res ( ss.str() );

std::cout << res;
```

from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034297/decimal-to-hex-conversion-c-built-in-function)
Be sure to search before.